# How to deploy Smart Contract on Ethereum 2.0

Tags: contract-deployment, eth-2.0

I want to know how to deploy Smart Contract on Ethereum 2 Testnet using web3 ?

Comment: What is "Ethereum 2 Testnet"? What have you tried so far? What technologies are you using?

Comment: I think, Ethereum (Proof of Stake) . I have deployed smart contract on rospten network using web3, Node js, Javascript

Answer (score 3):

The Eth 2.0 testnet is only the beacon chain. It doesn't yet support smart contracts.

Comment: so we can not test ethereum 2.0 by deploying Smart Contract or interact with already deployed Smart Contract

Comment: Ethereum 2.0 will add support for smart contracts in later phases. Unlikely to happen this year.

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum 2.0 is starting out with the beacon chain and it has no smart contracts for the forseeable future: [What is the difference between Ethereum 2.0 and the beacon chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87238/what-is-the-difference-between-ethereum-2-0-and-the-beacon-chain)

So you cannot deploy one.