# What is the difference between Ethereum 2.0 and the beacon chain?

Tags: eth-2.0, beacon-chain

There's a lot of promise to Ethereum 2.0 and questions like the following:

> [How to deploy Smart Contract on Ethereum 2.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84837/how-to-deploy-smart-contract-on-ethereum-2-0)
>
> [Will gas be free in ETH 2.0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/85326/will-gas-be-free-in-eth-2-0)
>
> [Does Ethereum 2.0 still have use cases for oracles, why?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/86842/does-ethereum-2-0-still-have-use-cases-for-oracles-why)
>
> [At which (average) rate will block numbers increase with ETH 2.0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/87172/at-which-average-rate-will-block-numbers-increase-with-eth-2-0)

Most of these questions are misunderstanding the difference between Ethereum 2.0 and the beacon chain.

What is that difference?

Answer (score 3):

Ethereum 2.0 consists of multiple phases.  Phase 0 is the [beacon-chain](/questions/tagged/beacon-chain) (with [proof-of-stake](/questions/tagged/proof-of-stake)).  Phase 1 is [sharding](/questions/tagged/sharding).  The beacon chain is expected 2020-2021.  Shards are targeted 2021-2022 (although there is slight parallel development with the beacon chain).

There can be subsequent phases but they are further out so can change.  For example, Phase 2 is about [state execution](https://ethresear.ch/c/eth2-phase-2) and cross-shard transactions but...

**More importantly, "Ethereum 1.0" and "Ethereum 2.0" will be merged before Phase 2.**

See https://blog.ethereum.org/2020/09/01/eth2-quick-update-no-15/ for the *eth1+eth2 (Phase 1.5 aka The Merge)* and its current [end-to-end demo](https://twitter.com/mkalinin2/status/1299038199591862274).

The questions in the OP are all about the subsequent phases of Ethereum 2.0 and are not applicable at this time.  **The beacon chain does not have smart contracts.**  This means that **for the foreseeable future, smart contract developers do not need to worry about anything about eth2**.  It is too early for any detailed answers about eth2 smart contracts, gas costs, oracles, accounts, transactions...

---

Giving each phase a name would have helped reduce the confusion.  Related [Casper, Serenity, Constantinople, Ethereum 2.0](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/62005/casper-serenity-constantinople-ethereum-2-0)

> There is no longer an Ethereum 2.0 if Vitalik can help it. What we
> call Ethereum 2.0 is simply the Serenity release and that's what he'd
> like it to be called though I'm sure Eth 2.0 will stick.