# Can we deploy old deployed NFT contract to Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, testnets, eth-2.0, nft

I have already deployed contract on Ethereum. Now I want to deploy it on Ethereum 2.0, is it possible? According to some resources Ethereum 2.0 does not support for smart contract deployment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: See this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/87238 for an explanation about how eth 2.0 will work.

Comment: @Ismael, Ok got the answer!